# How do I edit SSIS Script Tasks in Visual Studio 2019?

Tags: ssis, visual-studio-2019

Using the SSIS Data Tools extension for Visual Studio, it is possible to carry out various operations in a straightforward manner.  However VSTA and the Script Task are a major exception—specifically in VS 2019.

After editing an existing Script Task the script text will *reset to the* **default value**.

Creating a new Script Task (other than the default) is likewise impossible, as far as I can tell.

I have tried editing the base64 string in which the VSTA task is stored within my .dtsx files.

After that I tried manipulating the files and directory structure under the VSTA temp directory in order to persist changes in the scripting solutions/projects. I have also tried many other tactics, such as including the task implementation as an additional source file, as a binary reference, or via partial classes, a base class etc., within the Script Task.

But none of these approaches (even if they were to work) are necessarily maintainable or simple in the context of a team.

Is there any sustainable long-term alternative that allows Script Task development in VS 2019?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SQL Server Integration Services Projects extension for Visual Studio 2019 has a fix.

Script Task creation and editing appears to be working as of **version 3.2.1** of the extension.

This was apparently released some time in the past few weeks (as of date of writing, 26 November 2019).